# Java Selenium Cucumber tags - how to adjust test depending on the tag name?

Tags: java, selenium, mobile, cucumber

I have two scenarios with 2 different tags. How to adjust desired chrome capabilities depending on the tag ? For @mobile tag I want to run the following code:

```
DesiredCapabilities mobileCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
     ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
     options.addArguments("no-sandbox");
     options.setExperimentalOption("mobileEmulation", getMobileEmualtor());
     mobileCapabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);


 @desktop
  Scenario: Normal desktop test
Given Open landing page
Then I do normal test on desktop view


@mobile
  Scenario: Test with a user of smaller browser view
Given Open landing page
Then I chekc elements for mobile responsive page
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [tag expression](https://github.com/cucumber/tag-expressions#tag-expressions) in a hook

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-java#before--after

```java
public class StepDefinitions {

    private WebDriver driver;

    @Before("@mobile")
    public void before(Scenario scenario) {
        driver = createWebDriverForMobile();
    }

    @Before("not @mobile")
    public void before(Scenario scenario) {
        driver = createWebDriverForDesktop();
    }
    
    @Given("Open landing page")
    public void openLandingPage() {
        driver.get(....);
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, but where to invoke this method ? In feature file ?

Comment: I mean in which file invoke this method: public void before(Scenario scenario) {
    scenario.log("Runs before each scenario tagged with @mobile and *not* tagged with @android");
}

Comment: In your step definition file.

Comment: Added a bit more context to the example